# What is the size of a security cookie in PE file?

Tags: pe

I know that pointer to the security cookie in Load Configuration Directory is 4 bytes long for 32-bit exe and 8 bytes long for 64-bit one ([source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#load-configuration-layout)), but what is the size of the security cookie itself?

**Edit:** the accepted answer links to a long article, here's the quote from it:

> When /GS is specified, the compiler automatically links the object file built from **gs_cookie.c** source file. This file **defines __security_cookie as a 64-bit or 32-bit global variable of the type uintptr_t on x64 and x86, respectively.**

And since I can't find any official source for gs_cookie.c online here's the important part, which also shows the default values:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
#define DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE ((UINT_PTR)0x00002B992DDFA232)
#else  /* _WIN64 */
#define DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE ((UINT_PTR)0xBB40E64E)
#endif  /* _WIN64 */

UINT_PTR __security_cookie = DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE;
```

And just for completeness the documentation for [`UINT_PTR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/f959534d-51f2-4103-8fb5-812620efe49b) shows it's just `int` for 32-bit and `__int64` for 64-bit (both unsigned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie itself is the same size as a register, 64 bits or 32 bits.

The global cookie is copied into a register then xor'ed with RBP/EBP and stored on the stack.

When unwinding the frame the "stack cookie" is xor'ed against RBP/EBP again before being validated against the global cookie to ensure it hasn't been modified.

Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/december/c-visual-c-support-for-stack-based-buffer-protection